# JNDI vs HTTP/TCP

Tags: java, web-services, jndi

I am confused a bit. Is there a documentation which can explain which one is better or whether JNDI itself uses HTTP?

When should I be used JNDI? Does it make sense using JNDI to consume web services, or whether there are better/faster methods to consume web services?

Edit:
Adding a bit more context here. I am currently making a web service calls via HTTP REST. I am trying to understand that by invoking those services by JNDI, will I get any performance improvement?

Comment: You seem to be quite confused what JNDI is. You canoot compare it to HTTP or TCP.

Comment: @Henry Sure I am, which is why I have asked the same in my question only. Is there a documentation which can tell the difference?

Comment: There is no 'exact relation' to specify. Your question is meaningless. You're asking for a comparison between apples and oranges. There isn't one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't in competition for a moment. HTTP is used to communicate with HTTP servers. JNDI is used to communicate with naming services such as LDAP, the RMI registry, COS Naming, DNS, etc.

The overlap is zero.

Comment: So, JNDI doesn't uses HTTP to communicate? How does JNDI communicatation happens?

Comment: @gurvinder372 JNDI isn't a network protocol, it's a Java API. It communicates through Java methods.

Comment: It depends what you're talking to. Mostly TCP, or UDP in the case of DNS.

Comment: @EJP But the data transfer has to happen via a network that gets established between two JVMs, right? which protocol is used to transfer the data?

Comment: @chrylis Thanks, any pointers for this?

Comment: @gurvinder372 It's completely outside the scope of JNDI. If you're using RMI, it uses RMI. If you're using LDAP, it uses LDAP. Most of the time, the JNDI resources themselves are just made available internally by a container (EJB or Servlet).

Comment: @chrylis even if the resources are internal, data transfer (even the serialized object) has to get transferred via a protocol. I am trying understand what is it

Comment: @gurvinder372 The "protocol" *is the Java API*. It's the Java specification that says to push objects onto the JVM's stack and return to the calling method. JNDI says nothing more about serialization than `fopen` does; both might be getting stuff over the network, but there's a pluggable driver underneath that abstracts it into a library call.

Comment: @chrylis But this API uses some communication protocol to invoke methods and transfer data like HTTP, RMI, or Corba, right? Maybe I am not understanding this correctly. Any pointers where I could understand the communication protocols used by JNDI?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Wrong. It doesn't. JNDI itself does not have network communication protocols. Think of JNDI resources like files; it doesn't make any sense to ask about what protocol `File` uses. You can ask about what protocol a certain filesystem uses, but that's operating at a completely different layer.

Comment: @chrylis If you put it this way, I completely get that :) Thanks Please post your answer separately I can select that

Comment: @gurvinder372 You don't need another answer that says the same things you've already been told. Please look back at the answer here, and at my sole comment. You had already been told everything you have been asking about subsequently. You asked "which protocol is used to transfer the data?" immediately *after* I had already said TCP or UDP, and you then repeated the question several more times. The problem here is that you simply have not been listening to what you're being told..