# Consuming service via REST or via JNDI

Tags: java, web-services, jndi

which method would give better performance?

One method - Making HTTP URL connection to consumer REST services

Second method - Do a JNDI lookup and then invoke the API on the object to consume the service

Comment: Not so much a question of performance as of location transparency. Like in your other question of today it is hard to guess what you really want to know.

Comment: @Henry So, there is no difference in performance? Please let me know what is confusing in my question

Comment: Perhaps there is, but you are not going to see it. The biggest bottleneck you are going to have is network performance, not code performance. And since both ways will eventually do a HTTP call, there is no difference. You shouldn't worry about performance until you have an actual performance problem. Premature optimization is a very bad habit.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks. I can accept this as an answer (provided you post as an answer) if you can share some pointers which clearly tells that JNDI will use HTTP internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already answered in [JNDI vs HTTP/TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240181/jndi-vs-http-tcp), JNDI is independent of a transport protocol. It is just a Java API to access directory services.

Compare this to JDBC: It is a Java API to talk to a database. The actual communication is up to the JDBC driver. It may be even an in-memory database that is directly called or it may be a remote database that is called with a vendor specific network protocol.

In the second method you described in the question JNDI would be used to locate a stub object for the web service. Once the stub is obtained, JNDI is out of the game.

When a method on the stub is called, the stub will translate it to an HTTP request, since a RESTful web service is called. But once again, this is no longer JNDI which is doing it.

Performance wise, there is no difference except for the additional lookup step for the second method.